# Meaning of (generalized?) differential operator

Tags: probability-theory, differential-operators

I am currently reading this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2900) which makes use of generalized differential operators.

As I understood it, the operator $D_x$ works like this: If $F$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $G$ an (integrable?) function on $[a,b]$ then $D_x F = G$ means that there is a constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that

$F(x) = c + \int_a^x G(z) dz$.

(So actually quite ordinary, or did I miss something?)

My problem now is the following: At some point in this paper the author assumes $F$ to be a piecewise linear function on some interval $[0,l]$. She then takes $x_1, x_2 \in [0,l]$ and supposes that $F$ is linear between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and states the following:

$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} D_s F(s)^2 ds = \frac{\left[ F(x_2)-F(x_1) \right]^2}{x_2 - x_1}$

And I do not get that at all.

I mean, if my assumption was correct and $D_s$ actually means differentiation w.r.t. $s$ then $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} D_s F(s)^2 ds$ should be $F(x_2)^2-F(x_1)^2$, right?

Maybe someone knows the proper definition of this $D_s$ and can help me, please?

Comment: Okay, seems that if $D_s$ actually denotes a second derivative, then it works out because $F$ is piece-wise linear. Well, it works except a factor 2 ...But then on the other hand, $-D_m D_x$ is supposed to be a second order differential operator. That does not quite fit.

Comment: Is it $[D_x(F)(s)]^2$  in the integral ?

Comment: You mean like $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (D_s F(s))^2 ds$? That would fit indeed. There would even be no factor 2! Well, the brackets are definitely not there but maybe it is meant like this... Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.